# Type mismatch with date parameter using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, datetime, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a VBA sub routine as below which passes two parameters (date search to a sql server stored procedure).

```vb
Sub load_data()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim i, j As Date
'i = InputBox("Enter Date Start")
'j = InputBox("Enter Date Finish")
i = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
j = ActiveSheet.Range("B4")
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "Data Source=ashcourt_app1;"
strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog=ashcourt_weighsoft5;"
strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cn.Open strConn
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "ashcourt_invoiced_transactions"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Execute , i, j
Set rs = cmd.Execute()

End Sub
```

My stored procedure:

```
SELECT i.documentid, ia.quantity, ia.Outlet, i.invoicedate, t.EventTimestamp, convert(varchar(7), i.invoicedate, 126) as [invoice month], t.CollectionPostcode, ti.TotalPrice, ia.TotalPrice, 
t.AccountAddressName, t.CollectionAddressName,ia.ProductCode, ia.ProductDescription,
case
when a.AccountNo in('CA030','CE001','CS003','CA009','CA051','CA008','CM033') then 'Internal'
else 'External'
end as [Int/Ext], i.IsPosted
FROM [ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5].[dbo].[InvoiceItem] ia
inner join [ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5].[dbo].[TransactionItem] ti on ia.TransactionItemId = ti.id
inner join [ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5].[dbo].[Invoice] i on ia.InvoiceId = i.id
inner join [ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5].[dbo].[account] a on i.AccountId = a.Id
inner join [ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5].[dbo].[Transaction] t on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
where i.CompanyId = 4 and ia.UnitOfSaleCode = 'cm' and i.Deleted <> 1 and i.InvoiceDate >= @invoicestartdate and i.InvoiceDate <= @invoiceenddate
order by i.documentid
```

I run the sub on a command button and get the following error:

> "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Comment: How have you defined the parameters in your procedure?  What are the values of i & j at the time?

Comment: You don't seem to pass values to `@invoicestartdate` and `@invoiceenddate`.

Comment: Hi. There data entered is in short date format - 01/11/2021 and 30/11/2021. Thanks. Unless I'm wrong the vba code should pass the data to the parameters in the order defined by the cmd.execute.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by passing the parameters differently and formatting them into the correct date/time format for the variables in the stored procedure

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DocumentID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Format(Range("B3").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("DocumentID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Format(Range("B4").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```